# not able to make ontap function due to The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()' what to do?

Tags: flutter, dart

[Cannot make onTap function due to The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()   So frustrating i was following a video and he successfully created the function but i am seeing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwRGk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tip is the question mark.
You have

```
void Function()?
```

onTap needs a not-nullable value:

```
void Function()
```

You need to wrap the function variable:

```
onTap : onTap!
```

or to prevent a crash you can just give an empty function to call when onTap is null:

```
onTap : onTap ?? (){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. set onTap function like below. refer InkWell class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html)

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        //write your onTap void function here
        print('Pressed');
      },
      child:Container(),//or your widget here
    ),
```